# Vim-fugitive not matching Git command line

Tags: git, vim, vim-fugitive

I installed [vim-fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) using pathogen.

If I do `git status` in a terminal window, I get the correct branch and status. 
If in Vim, I do `:Git status`, I see the same that was in the terminal window (no surprise).

But if in Vim, I do `:Gstatus`, the results are completely wrong: it's the wrong branch, and a list of files that have **already been committed** are showing as staged but not committed.

Since this plugin is one of TPope's, I'm sure it is my error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What you are doing wrong is asking here instead of creating an issue on the plugin's issue tracker. ;-)

Comment: What does `:echo b:git_dir` show? Is that correct?

Comment: :echo b:git_dir shows the correct location of the .git directory for this project.

Comment: I didn't post to the issue tracker because 1) I'm reasonably confident that the issue is with me and not the plugin, and 2) I don't want Tim to call me an idiot. I don't mind if you do.

Comment: @Bob why not put in a ticket with the issue tracker anyways?  Maybe someone or TPope himself can take a look and see if you're doing something wrong, or if it's an actual bug.

Comment: Are you using a GIT_INDEX_FILE environment variable to specify an alternate index? If so, maybe `:Gstatus` is not using it for some reason.